# Error importing a package that was forked and edited in a Next.JS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

I'm using react-headroom for this project and needed to edit its code so the `<header>` wouldn't adjust height for pages. Therefore, I forked the original [repo](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-headroom) and made the change on my version so I could install it in my project using `yarn add <my-git-repo-url>` and then normally import it as any other library:

```
// src/components/layout.js
import { useState } from "react"
import { Box, Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Footer from "../footer"
import Header from "../header"
import Headroom from "react-headroom" // react-headroom imported here

(...)
```

However, I'm getting this error telling me that module was not found:
[image: This is the result of localhost:3000]

I'm not sure if there's any mistake with this process (I think not) but was unable to fix this. I ran `yarn install` in both `./` and `./node_modules/react-headroom` with no changes at all for this result.

As @novonimo asked, here it is the module's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-headroom",
  "description": "Hide your header until you need it. React.js port of headroom.js",
  "version": "3.2.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-headroom/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "raf": "^3.3.0",
    "shallowequal": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-undefined-to-void": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha-unfunk-reporter": "^0.4.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.0.5",
    "prettier": "2.1.2"
  },
  "directories": {
    "example": "examples"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-headroom",
  "keywords": [
    "headroom",
    "react",
    "react-component"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0 || ^17"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/KyleAMathews/react-headroom.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel --copy-files src --out-dir dist",
    "test-watch": "NODE_ENV=test node_modules/.bin/mocha -w --recursive --compilers coffee:babel-core/register -R mocha-unfunk-reporter",
    "unit-test": "NODE_ENV=test node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive --compilers coffee:babel-core/register -R mocha-unfunk-reporter",
    "test": "npm run unit-test && npm run lint",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "publish-patch": "npm run build && npm version patch && npm publish; git push; git push --tags",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore src/*",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore . --fix",
    "format": "prettier --config .prettierrc --write 'src/**/*.{js,jsx}'"
  }
}
```

Comment: add the forked module package.json (which is in `/node_module/react-headroom`)

Comment: Sure. Here it go.

Comment: did you build the forked repo before using it?

Comment: I didn't know it was needed. This was the problem, thanks! Shall I update with the answer or would you like to do it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to build your forked library with the `build` command.

So, build it:

```
npm build
// or
yarn build
```

Now use it without any issues on your application:

```
import Headroom from "react-headroom"
```

**Note:** you need to run the above command in your forked directory not the root of your project.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I wasn't aware of this. This is my first forked and edited repo.

Comment: good luck bro @EduardoOliveira

Comment: Opening another question about this.

Comment: about what ? @EduardoOliveira

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Had to fix my PC. This is the new question related to this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780855/vercel-deployment-error-module-not-found-remotelly-works-locally-cached-build I guess I've deleted the comment with the context because it was sort of duplicated